How to Exclude Custom Exception Classes from pytest-cov
I am working on a project that includes several custom exception classes, and I aim to achieve 100% test coverage. However, I do not want to test the initialization of every exception, as these tests are redundant and would unnecessarily bloat my test suite. Most of my exceptions simply store extra information in instance variables, and some have overridden __str__() methods.
GitHub Copilot suggested excluding every __init__() method, which is not a desirable solution. It also suggested manually adding each exception class to be excluded, but this approach does not scale well.
I am considering excluding every class that ends with "Error" or "Exception" from the coverage report. However, I haven't found a way to implement this.
Does anyone have any advice or solutions for excluding specific exception classes from test coverage in a scalable manner?
Thank you!

Have you tried putting # pragma: nocover at the top of the class? That's what I do to exclude lines from coverage.

Thank you for that suggestion. It worked for me. If somebody is reading this afterwards, please note that # pragma: nocover needs to be put in the same line as the class definition.
